# Why declaring a QImage as static const produces an invalid value?

Tags: c++, qt, static, constants, qimage

I have a `QGraphicsItem` object called `ItemView` which I am creating many instances of, and they all show up as a `QImage` on my `QGraphicsView`.

I have it working by creating a new `QImage` for each instance of `ViewItem`, but now I'm trying to convert that property to a static field to optimize because I really only need one, and I just cant get it to work.

As a test I added a `static const int` next to the `QImage` and that works just fine.

```cpp
// .hh
class ViewItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    ...
private:
    static const QImage IMAGE;
    static const int TEST;
};

//.cc
const QImage ViewItem::IMAGE = QImage(":/data/data/img.png");
const int ViewItem::TEST = 30;
```

breakpoint in my `QGraphicsItem::paint()` method shows IMAGE value as `(invalid)` but TEST shows `30` as expected.

Why is it working for `int` but not `QImage`?

Comment: You should avoid to create a QImage statically, because the constuctor is called before the QApplication is initialized, and the loading can fail

Comment: Hmm I was worried it would be something like that. So to optimize I should probably instantiate the QImage somewhere else and just pass a pointer to it to these ViewItem instances?

Comment: You can create a function that returns the static image: QImage getImage() { static QImage img("path"); return img; } ) . The image  is initialized the first time the function is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** For me this is a XY problem. I will provide a solution to the X problem and I suggest you to think about your Y problem and probably ask another question, which targets it explicitly.

## Cause

You initialize `ViewItem::IMAGE` with a `QImage`, constructed from a `fileName`. As per [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-8):

> If the loading of the image failed, this object is a null image.

The loading fails, because the resource file is not available at the time, at which `ViewItem::IMAGE` is initialized.

## Solution to X

To get the expected result, instead of a resource image, use an image from the disk, located in the `data/data/` subfolder with respect to the build folder:

```
const QImage ViewItem::IMAGE = QImage("data/data/img.png");
```

The image would exist at the time of the initialization, so the constructor would succeed to create a valid `QImage`. To test this, call:

```
qDebug() << TEST << IMAGE;
```

in the constructor of `ViewItem`. It would produce a similar result:

> 30 QImage(QSize(256, 256),format=QImage::Format_ARGB32,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=1024,sizeInBytes=262144)